# Redis server 'make test' failure when running in Alpine Docker

Tags: docker, redis-server

I am installing a redis server within a docker container using the following steps

```
- wget https://download.redis.io/releases/redis-6.2.4.tar.gz
- tar xvf redis-6.2.4.tar.gz
- cd redis-6.2.4
- make
```

When I run `make test` I get the following failure. Anyone has an idea what this means and how this may impact my installation?

```
> !!! WARNING The following tests failed:

*** [err]: BITFIELD overflow detection fuzzing in tests/unit/bitfield.tcl
OW not detected where needed: i64 -9223372036854775808+-9223372036854775808
Cleanup: may take some time... OK
make[1]: *** [Makefile:383: test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/delphix/redis/redis-6.2.4/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: test] Error 2
```

Followed instructions on downloading and installing redis on Linux.
Expecting a successful output to `make test`

Comment: https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/9035